# Google snippet tree structure

Tags: sitemap, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

How can I get a snippet like in the picture below in google page results?

I submitted a **sitemap.xml** in *google webmaster tools* **3 months ago**, but there is no change until now?
Do you know how I should proceed to get this Result? Or the name (keyword) of this structure?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you can force Google to create these shortlinks to your website. I believe they will only show up if your site is in the top ranks of the search query. Another thing might be the relevance of the page or the internal structure that doesn't tigger Google to create it for you.

Comment: Effectively, my site is in the first line of search result. https://goo.gl/oMsDAv

Comment: As far as I can see your site doesn't use semantic navigation. I would recommend anyway to use <header> and <nav> elements. This might help search engines to better understand your site. A sitemap tells only what sites are available and how important they are. Perhaps have a look at this hints: https://goo.gl/fwPDqa

Comment: Thanks! it should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the keyword I was looking for is "[Google Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)".

Here as some documentations about it :

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview
- http://bloggerspassion.com/google-site-links-how-to-get-google-sitelinks-for-your-website/

Thanks to @Mark.